# obtaining the instruction stream (byte or assembly) for function within a shared object file (ELF)

Tags: assembly, binary, pyelftools

I am working on getting the instructions associated with a certain function within a shared object file (ELF).

This shall be realized from a python script. I could do this certainly from the command line whereby the goal is not fire up cli commands from my python script. A library ought to be used instead.

The input for my script is an object filename and the name of the function like

```
    python getInstructionStream.py main.o foo
```

The result should look like

```
    00000016 <foo>:
    16: 55                      push   ebp
    17: 89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
    19: 83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
    1c: 8b 45 0c                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    1f: 8b 55 08                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
    22: 01 d0                   add    eax,edx
    24: 89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
    27: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
    2a: c9                      leave  
    2b: c3                      ret
```

It is not a must have to show the output in any assembly syntax. A hex stream is also sufficient. Can anyone name me one or more libraries which can help me for this kind of work?

Comment: This sounds a great deal like you're asking someone to write the code for you.  That's not how stack overflow works.  You write code and when you run into trouble you ask for help.

Comment: I do not want anyone to write code for me. I am asking for library support.

Comment: But I must admit the question was not so well formulated. Next time I'll do better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the libelf hint. I can go on from here